# Normal directory shown as submodule on github

Tags: git, github

I save a repository on GitHub, but I can't synchronize some of my directories as they are shown as submodule (gray folder symbol). I already tried to steps to remove submodules, but they don't work (git doesn't recognize any steps to commit). If I use

```
git add dir/*
```

instead of

```
git add dir
```

I get the error message

> fatal: Pathspec 'dir/subdir' is in submodule 'dir'

But

```
git submodule deinit dir/
```

gives

> No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'dir'.

I don't have a `.gitmodules` file to begin with.
I realized that the error occurs when I merge a branch, the new directories are not pushed to GitHub.

Comment: I am running into this problem - were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

A nested repository is a submodule.  If you don't give the submodule command a name and any other information about the path that might be useful, it can't really do anything -- just as you can work with remote repositories, push and fetch and ls-remote and so on, but the git remote command can't really do anything unless you tell it a name and whatever other information might be useful to go with the remote path or url.

Comment: I don't really understand what this means for me, as I am quite new to git. I never intended to nest my repository, does this mean I have to search for unwanted `.git` directories in my directories? I just do some work on a branch and then want to merge it into my project again. I gave the submodule command the name `dir` to work with.

Comment: Well, _somebody_ put those nested repositories in your workspace.  So far as I'm aware, "git init" and "git clone" aren't generally considered easy to unintentionally type.

Comment: I am fully aware that I must have done something wrong, else there wouldn't be any problems. The question is still the same, how do I fix it?

Comment: It's difficult to answer that, because it's not clear where those repositories came from or whether they should be there.  If you didn't create them, somebody else did. Find somebody who knows how your project should be set up and ask them.

Answer (score 0):

An ugly workaround is to simply zip the directories in question. It doesn't really fix the problem, but at least makes it possible to backup the directories.